# Using jQuery Autocomplete with Meteor.js

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to hook up autocomplete with the following code:

```
      .autocomplete({
        source: function(request, callback) {
           Meteor.call('searchContacts', request.term, function(err, results) {
             console.log("why won't you call me?");
             callback(results);
           });
    },
    search: function() {
```

Update:
Here is my search method:

```
  searchContacts: function(term) {
     console.log(`search for ${term}`);
     return Contacts.find({'$or' : [
      { 'name': {$regex: term, $options: 'i'} },
      { 'email': {$regex: term, $options: 'i'} } ]
    });
  },
```

Oddly, the Meteor.call to searchContacts never responds so the callback is never fired. I did some console debugging on the server methods and it gets into searchContacts and even finds results, but it never hits the callback. Any help would be great. thanks.

Comment: Can you post your searchContacts method? Possibly silly, but my concern is you might not be returning anything on the server method.

Comment: Sure thing. I just updated my original post with the search method. Thanks.